# Custom Windows 11 taskbar setting for an OLED display

Tags: windows, user-interface, themes

I have a Windows 11 pc that I have been trying to optimize for an OLED display to reduce burn in risk.

So far I have set my own custom high-contrast theme that works very well for open windows on the screen. I set the taskbar to auto-hide mode, but the taskbar still has a small white line sliver that sits just above on the black screen.
Screenshot:[image: Taskbar Example]

I have even gone into the `users/*username*/APPDATA/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/`

folder and edited a custom high contrast version of the built-in "Night Sky" theme and changed values shown here:

```
    [Control Panel\Colors]
    ActiveTitle=4 4 4
    Background=0 0 0
    ButtonFace=0 0 0
    ButtonText=128 128 128
    GrayText=64 64 64
    Hilight=128 128 128
    HilightText=32 32 32
    HotTrackingColor=32 32 32
    InactiveTitle=1 1 1
    InactiveTitleText=0 0 0 
    TitleText=0 0 0 
    Window=0 0 0
    WindowText=128 128 128
    Scrollbar=0 0 0
    Menu=0 0 0
    WindowFrame=64 64 64
    MenuText=64 64 64
    ActiveBorder=0 0 0
    InactiveBorder=32 32 32
    AppWorkspace=0 0 0
    ButtonShadow=32 32 32
    ButtonHilight=64 64 64
    ButtonDkShadow=64 64 64
    ButtonLight=32 32 32
    InfoText=92 92 92
    InfoWindow=0 0 0
    ButtonAlternateFace=64 64 64
    GradientActiveTitle=64 64 64
    GradientInactiveTitle=32 32 32
    MenuHilight=64 64 64
    MenuBar=0 0 0
```

These settings work great for an OLED, but for some reason I cannot get rid of the white line sliver on the top of the Taskbar which continues to show and risk burn in for hours even with the auto hide setting on.

There is one setting that does work to change the color of the line in the list called "WindowText=128 128 128", but if I set that to zero, it also sets all my text to black.

I have also tried changing my over-scan settings on my monitor and shifting my pixels down, but since it is an OLED screen, it has built in pixel shifting and a locked aspect ratio.

I am at my end trying to figure out how to solve this. I do not want to install any third party programs either. I do not understand why Microsoft has not addressed an OLED theme for windows yet, since they are becoming more popular and are better for the eyes.

Please, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre W11 2H2: There is a [study on this proposal](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows_Redesign/comments/11nizu2/windows_11_theme_for_oled_displays_concept/):

[image: https://preview.redd.it/psqj6j5cbvma1.png?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=df115b16aadbda75587ecc99b637eea2edd9d855]

But nothing implemented yet.

The line that you see is a design element from Microsoft, and changing it requires modifications to the `shellstyle.dll` file, referenced for instance in [`SHGetShellStyleHInstance` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb762202(v=vs.85)).

The black background [mentioned in this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/11o72r0/bug_oled_wearandtear_major_insider_build_update/) remains the usual approach, combined in your case with [Auto-Hide Your Windows 11 Taskbar](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/auto-hide-windows-taskbar): check if that would help, even though that would be a workaround.

---

The [OP Infinity Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8111012/infinity-loop) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76608237/custom-windows-11-taskbar-setting-for-an-oled-display/76667351#comment135470904_76667351):

> It looks like Windows 11 22H2 feature update fixed the issue.
> The taskbar hides a few pixels lower in the latest update

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks like Windows 11 22H2 feature update fixed the issue. The taskbar hides a few pixels lower in the latest update.

Comment: @InfinityLoop Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment for more visibility.